# Apostroph in Query (MariaDB)

Tags: sql, mariadb

How ist the following SQL-Statement correct..

Insert into Songs (Title) values ('A Gangsta's Paradise');

The string-value has an apostroph inside

Answer (score 0):

If you want a single quote in a string, then the SQL standard is to double-it-up:

```
insert into Songs (Title)
    values ('A Gangsta''s Paradise');
----------------------^ two single quotes
```

Answer (score 0):

You can escape a single quote(') with another additional single quote('') or with a back slash('):

```
insert into Songs (Title)
    values ('A Gangsta''s Paradise');
```

or

```
insert into Songs (Title)
    values ('A Gangsta\'s Paradise');
```

DB-FIDDLE:

```
 create table Songs (Title varchar(50));
```

Query#1:

```
 insert into Songs (Title)
     values ('A Gangsta''s Paradise');


 select * from Songs;
```

Output:

| Title |
| --- |
| A Gangsta's Paradise |

Query#2:

```
 insert into Songs (Title)
     values ('A Gangsta\'s Paradise');
```

Output:

| Title |
| --- |
| A Gangsta's Paradise |
| A Gangsta's Paradise |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=0ee72f9908d2ac0335cc9f74c935790c)*